# Loading scripts based off conditions

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, scriptcs, csx

I am currently working with a bunch of c sharp scripts and I want to implement this such that each script will be quite unique for a certain task .
Which is why I want to #load certain script when a certain condition is fulfilled.
But seems like by trying tom do so is not allowed in scriptcs

**ERROR: Error executing script 'app.csx' [InvalidDirectiveUseException] Encountered directive '#load' after the start of code. Please move this directive to the beginning of the file.**

What I would like to know is whether there is any alternative method to implement a similar functionality in csx

Below is a code from what I hope to achieve

```
string value ="1";
if(value.Equals("1"))
{
#load install1.csx
}

else if(value.Equals("2"))
{
#load install2.csx
}

else
{
#load install3.csx
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`#load` can only be placed at the top (before first using statement or code line) of your CSX file.
if you place `#load` inline out script pre-processor will simply exclude it. This is in-line with C# REPL/C# Interactive Window behavior.

Comment: oh ok ...I understand. but is there any way we can work around to get a similiar outcome atleast ?

Comment: You can have a script conditionally writing the final script that will be executed.