# Is there a way to run a #load directive conditionally in a csx file?

Tags: c#, .net, preprocessor-directive, csx

I am new to C# and C# interactive scripts.
I would like to load a script conditionally.

After consulting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59770450/8650088), I know that #load statements are preprocessor directives that must be at the top of the file. I was thinking of a workaround where I use an #if clause as so:

```cs
#if false
    #load "path/to/script.csx"
#endif
```

This does not seem to work unless I am missing something. Could this work? Is there any other way to do this? Thanks.